# Automated VBA Solver in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a project which has some requirements for VBA. The data is found in excel. What I need to ask/bounce ideas off of is for a way to write some code that will abide to the following conditions:

where Xmw and Ymw are in megawatt, and X and Y are generation plants

`Xmw=<1000`   -always true

and

`Ymw=<1000`    -always true

`2000=Xmw+Ymw` -Equation 1

and

`10=X+Y` -Equation 2

Essentially, since the maximum absolute value of generation to increase and decrease is 2000, and the maximum amount of plants that can be used is 10. I'm stuck at this point because I can't find the relation between the 2 equations.  Additionally, the existing program identifies generation to use, but it doesn't follow it to the 2 provided equations.

Existing programming identifies which generation plants are in the "pools" of X and Y.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing two critical pieces of data => How many megawatts are produced by an **X** and how many are produced by a **Y**

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying in terms of the equations, but it seems to me that the paragraph following that is a little, well... hard to follow. If you could clear up exactly what it is you are looking to get out of the VBA macro, I think you would be more likely to receive an answer(Also, existing program? What does it do/look like?)

Comment: "I can't find the relation between the 2 equations." Yes because there is none. As  Gary's Student mentioned it lacks a relation between X and Xmw and Y and Ymw.

Comment: After the edit, it looks like the relation between the two equations lies in the megawatt output of the power plants. Do Xmw and Ymw represent the outputs of the two power plant groups, X and Y?

Comment: @usfbs yes, that is correct. Xmw and Ymw represent the outputs of each group respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this in an answer because it would be too much to post in a comment (please comment and let me know if this hits the mark)

You could use a conditional that looks something like this:

```
power_generated=Ymw+Xmw

if power_generated<>2000 then
    'do stuff here to add another power plant to generation
    '
    '
    if X+Y>10 then
        'deal with the fact that you have not enough power plants to deal with your draw
    end if
end if
```

Comment: Nice, I am going to try this out. But i think for the second if statement, it should be X+Y<10?

Comment: yes it should be. I'm actually going to change it to `<=10`, only because you are going to be able to have a max of ten plants going at a time.

Comment: or wait... do you want there to be exactly ten at all times?

Comment: Per your second comment, no, it does not always need to sum up to 10, just to be less than or equal to 10.

Comment: @Boom ok, then the way i have the code is what you would want. The reason for that being that you only want the code to do something special with the power plants if there are more power plants required than available (i.e., you require 11 plants). Just having `X+Y>10` does that.